# By what means do "nerve agent" compounds like VX spread through the human body so quickly?

Tags: neuroscience, toxicology, circulatory-system

It has been demonstrated that so-called nerve agents are able to incapacitate and kill a human in only minutes after exposure. One such substance, [VX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VX_(nerve_agent)), only requires a few milligrams to contact the skin of a human in order to trigger such a reaction.

I understand that many nerve agents are acetylcholinesterase inhibitors, so they promote a surplus of acetylcholine which causes loss of muscle control due to the inability to "rest."

What I totally fail to understand (or find in my searches), is how such a small drop of e.g. VX is able to cause full-body symptoms. In other words, if a drop of this substance gets on a person's hand, how is it that in 1-2 minutes, they begin to have full-body convulsions, defecate uncontrollably, etc...? I would understand this if the substance was sprayed all over someone, but having a drop in the order of milligrams on an extremity, it's not clear how this triggers such a severe reaction all over the body. I am aware that it gets absorbed through the skin, but otherwise I have no idea what happens after that.

My lack of understanding is partially due to:

> (A) Neurotransmitter (acetylcholine, ACh) released from nerve endings binds to receptors (AChRs) on the muscle surface.

Kuo IY, Ehrlich BE. Signaling in muscle contraction. Cold Spring Harb Perspect Biol. 2015;7(2):a006023. Published 2015 Feb 2. doi:10.1101/cshperspect.a006023

How does VX so quickly get to the surfaces and inhibit acetylcholinesterase all over the body? Is it a matter of simple blood circulation after the agent makes its way through the skin and into the blood stream?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your post to clarify your question. As written you seem to be asking about the [circulatory system](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279250/), but since that is common knowledge I'm guessing you have a more sophisticated question that isn't clear.

Comment: hi @tyersome thanks for explaining that. So I made a minor edit to clarify the final question. After doing a bit of research on *that* subject, I found that the circulatory system can indeed push blood in full circulation from heart and back in a matter of sub minute. But I'm still only speculating here.

Comment: You're welcome! It seems to me that all of the symptoms you describe could occur due to effects on the CNS, so a nerve agent doesn't even need to get to the whole body. I'm doubtful that anyone on this stack has the kind of background to answer this with any specificity — you could try [MedicalSciences.SE], but be aware they may expect more prior research. Also, please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/), instead request migration after consulting that sites help.